# Performing OOP style in Login System

Tags: php, oop

I know my question is easy to anyone. Just learning this PHP almost one month. I tried to perform my login system using OOP style. Where I need to login as a default user where the username and password is admin. When I tried to login it's saying object not found.

[image: Object not found!]

So here my code below.

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE loginmodule
(
loginId INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
loginUsername VARCHAR(50),
loginPassword VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Here is my login script.

**loginMe.php**

```
<?php
require_once('../connection/connection.php');
require_once('../connection/loginCRUD.php');
require_once('../process/createProcess.php');
?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Login Frame</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div id = "container">
     <h1>Login</h1>
     <form action = "post" action = "../process/createProcess.php">

    <div class = "form-field">
        <input type = "text" id = "username" name = "loginUsername" placeholder = "Enter Username">
    </div>

    <div class = "form-field">
        <input type = "password" id = "password" name = "loginPassword" placeholder = "Enter Password">
    </div>

    <div class = "form-field">
        <input type = "submit" id = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Login">
    </div>
    </form>
    </div><!--- end container --->
   </body>
   </html>
```

So I set aside my CRUD in another file.
**loginCRUD.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
class CRUD
{
 public function readLogin($dbusername,$dbpassword)
 {
    global $myDatabase;
    $result = $myDatabase->query("SELECT * FROM loginmodule WHERE loginUsername = '$dbusername' AND loginPassword = '$dbpassword'");

    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        return $row;
    }
}
}
?>
```

Last where I set aside also my process where my validation happens.
 **createProcess.php**

```
<?php

require_once('../connection/connection.php');
require_once('../connection/loginCRUD.php');

session_start();

$dbusername = $_POST['loginUsername']; //Get the value from textfield.
$dbpassword = $_POST['loginPassword'];

if(!empty($dbusername) && !empty($dbpassword))
{
    if($loginUsername == $dbusername && $loginPassword == $dbpassword)
    {
        $create = loginCRUD::readLogin($dbusername,$dbusername);
        echo "You are logged in!";
        @$_SESSION['loginUsername'] = $loginUsername;
    }
}

?>
```

Guide me if I missed something. If there's a shortcut style than this let me know :)

Comment: Can you update the question with the full error message please? It will be easier to help you.

Comment: `$myDataase` is a typo. Should be `$myDatabase`, right?

Comment: This statement, `if($loginUsername == $dbusername && $loginPassword == $dbpassword){ ...`, from where did you get `$loginUsername` and `$loginPassword`?

Comment: You should use parameterized queries as well with prepared statements. This is open to SQL injections as is. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: If your passwords are plain text that also is a separate issue you should correct. http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/

Comment: @chris85 I didn't notice the type. Just trying to learn this also will move on to Prepared Statements after this :)

Comment: Also this statement, `$create = loginCRUD::readLogin($dbusername,$dbusername);` is wrong. You have to create an instance of class `CRUD` to call it's method `readLogin()`.

Comment: @MiaLegaspi Create an object of class `CRUD` and call it's method `readLogin()`, like this: `(new CRUD)->readLogin($dbusername,$dbpassword);`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Sorry I forgot an object. Already create an instance of class but still not working.

Comment: @MiaLegaspi I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several errors in your code, such as:

- There are two action attribute in your `form` tag.

  ```
  <form action = "post" action = "../process/createProcess.php">
          ^                ^
  ```

  It should be,

  ```
  <form method="post" action="../process/createProcess.php">
  ```
- On **createProcess.php** page, look at the following lines,

  ```
  1) if($loginUsername == $dbusername && $loginPassword == $dbpassword)
              ^                                 ^
  ```

  There are no variables named `$loginUsername` and `$loginPassword`

  ```
  2) $create = loginCRUD::readLogin($dbusername,$dbusername);
                                         ^            ^ 
                                   both the arguments are same
  ```

  You're calling `readLogin()` method in a wrong way. You should first create an instance of class `CRUD` and then call it's instance method `readLogin()`, like this way:

  ```
     (new CRUD)->readLogin($dbusername,$dbpassword);

  3) $_SESSION['loginUsername'] = $loginUsername;
  ```

  As I said, there is no variable named `$loginUsername`. It should be,

  ```
  $_SESSION['loginUsername'] = $dbusername;
  ```
- Always start session at your very top of your PHP script, right after the opening PHP tag, like this:

  ```
  <?php 
      session_start();
      // your code
  ```
- Your query is susceptible to SQL injection. Use prepared statements for [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent any kind SQL injection. [And this is how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
- Never store password as a plain readable text, always perform [salted password hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) on raw password before inserting it into the table.
- **Suggestion:** Don't use `global` in your code. [Why Globals are evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/5517143)

So your code should be like this:

**CRUD class:**

```
class CRUD{
    public function readLogin($dbusername,$dbpassword){
        global $myDatabase;
        $statement = $myDatabase->prepare("SELECT * FROM loginmodule WHERE loginUsername = ? AND loginPassword = ? LIMIT 1");
        $statement->bind_param("ss", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
        if($statement->execute()){
            $result = $statement->get_result();
            if($result->num_rows){
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                return $row;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**createProcess.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $dbusername = $_POST['loginUsername'];
    $dbpassword = $_POST['loginPassword'];

    if(!empty($dbusername) && !empty($dbpassword)){
        if((new CRUD)->readLogin($dbusername,$dbpassword)){
            echo "You are logged in!";
            $_SESSION['loginUsername'] = $dbusername;

            // redirect the user to the home page
        }else{
            echo "Incorrect username and/or password";
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id = "container">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method = "post" action = "../process/createProcess.php">
        <div class = "form-field">
            <input type = "text" id = "username" name = "loginUsername" placeholder = "Enter Username">
        </div>

        <div class = "form-field">
            <input type = "password" id = "password" name = "loginPassword" placeholder = "Enter Password">
        </div>

        <div class = "form-field">
            <input type = "submit" id = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Login">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This was the best explanation that I encounter. Last question what is the purpose of `"ss"` in `$statement->bind_param("ss", $dbusername, $dbpassword);`

Comment: @MiaLegaspi `s` specifies the type for the corresponding bind variable. Here `"ss"` means both `$dbusername` and `$dbpassword` is of type `string`. Here's [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).